# how to add border to progress bar done in css3 and jquery

Tags: css, progress-bar, border

## Long story short

Used progress bar code from CSS tricks. Cannot add border to the progress bar without making it look worse.

## Long story

I used the progress bar code from CSS tricks [here](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/)

I made several changes to the original code to get something that looks like this

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8743819/reducedtestcase/ProgressBars/custombar.html

## What I wanted to accomplish

1. the meter > span has a gradient **(done)**
2. the meter and span are snug tight with no spacing between them **(done)**
3. the span has a 1 or 2px border of a different color.

Note that those marked **(done)** are accomplished. Please see the demo [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8743819/reducedtestcase/ProgressBars/custombar.html).

## What I tried and gotten as a result

- I have tried adding border to the meter > span but that resulted in the span being much larger.
- I have tried adding padding to the meter > span. Same story.
- I have tried adding margin to the meter itself. Then it looks like there is spacing.

## What I need

Requirements 1 , 2, and 3 to work.

## FAQs

1. is this your full app?

No. I did a reduced test case where i stripped out as much un-necessary code to explain my problem without affecting the problem statement as possible.

## Disclosure

1. I have cross-posted this same question at css-tricks.com over [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/21212/how-to-add-border-to-progress-bar-done-in-css3-and-jquery#Item_1) to gather greater attention to my problem.

## Final solution

Final solution posted [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8743819/reducedtestcase/ProgressBars/custombarsolved.html) as part of demo.

Comment: what do you mean by big one, @RhoHappy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand your question you can use CSS **box-sizing** property for this. Write like this:

```
.meter > span{
 border:2px solid red;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

For more you can read this http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: i am going to cross post your answer at css tricks forum. with a link back here and a hat tip

Answer (score 0):

I've tried adding a `border-width:2px` to the span and as you mentioned this then extends out of the parent `div`. But if you account for this with the heights it seems to look ok. Please see below.

Set the parent div height to 24px `.meter {height:24px;}`

Instead of height 100% set the span height to 20px `.meter > span {height:20px;}`

And to fix the width set the parent divs padding to `.meter {padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}`

I'm sure that isn't the correct method but it seems to look ok.

**IN SUMMARY**

`.meter {height:24px; padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;}`

`.meter > span {height:20px;}`

Comment: i hope you did upvote my question. Thanks for acknowledging my efforts at clarifying my problem description.